# NULL vs nullptr in a ported c header

Tags: c++, c++11, null, coding-style, standards

I'm using [std::getenv](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) call inside my code and I'm not sure about these three choices -

```
const char *env_p = std::getenv("SOME_ENV");

if(env_p == NULL){
    std::cout << "NULL caught";
}

if(env_p == 0){
    std::cout << "0 caught";
}

if(env_p == nullptr){
    std::cout <<"nullptr caught";
}
```

which one of them should I use? I was more inclined towards `nullptr` version since c++ recommends it, but since `cstdlib` was originally a c header, I'm not sure to check for `NULL` or `0` or `nullptr`.

I ran a program to check and all three were caught because there wasn't an env variable with above name. So this gives me the choice that I might use anyone of them or even `if(!env_p)` right?

But I'm not so sure since this might only work for this example or machine dependent or something I might be missing. So anyone can confirm this case?

Thankyou

Comment: `nullptr` will naturally work with any pointer, even those you pass to C functions where it will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, they're all the same.  A null pointer is a pointer with a magic value that won't match any pointer to actual data.  Typically, we think of it as address 0, and most implementations actually use address 0 to represent a null pointer, but that's an implementation detail.

```
if (env_p == 0)
```

This literal `0` is being compared to a pointer, so the compiler will convert it to a pointer.  A literal zero converted to a pointer results in a null pointer because the standards say so.

```
if (env_p == NULL)
```

This is effectively the same thing because, in almost all implementations, `NULL` is a macro defined to be `0`.  (For a while, it was not uncommon for C to define `NULL` as `(void*)0`, but that's not in style anymore for reasons that aren't important here.)

```
if (env_p == nullptr)
```

`nullptr` is a C++ keyword that gives you a null pointer with a special type.  But it's still just a null pointer, so it does exactly what you want.

There are cases in C++ (like perfect forwarding) where you must use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` or `0` to guarantee that you have a null pointer (rather than a int that happens to be 0) in order to ensure type deduction chooses the write template instantiation or overload.

Finally, common idioms for checking pointers are:

```
if (env_p) { ... } // true if not a null pointer
if (!env_p) { ... } // true if a null pointer
```

This works because there's an implicit comparison for inequality to 0.  That is, they're treated exactly as if you had written:

```
if ((env_p) != 0) { ... }
if ((!env_p) != 0) { ... }
```

So it works for the reasons stated above.

In C++, I use `nullptr` for null pointers.  In C or in code that may be compiled in either mode, I typically use `NULL` because it makes the intent a tiny bit clearer than using `0`.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** They are all the same, you can use them interchangeably.

**Slightly longer answer:**

[std::getenv](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) returns a `NULL` pointer if it fails:

> Character string identifying the value of the environmental variable or **null pointer** if such variable is not found.

If you want check if the function failed, you can use either of these:

- `if (env_p == NULL)` is defined as `0` (`#define NULL 0`)
- `if (env_p == 0)` is the same thing
- `if (env_p == nullptr)` is a  C++ way of doing it - safe (can only be compared against pointers)
- `if (!env_p)` is only `true` when `env_p` is `false`, so it is the same as checking `env_p == 0`

If you are using modern C++, I would stick to `nullptr`.